# Selectively triggering a model _post_put_hook

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have set up a _post_put_hook on an ndb model that updates some search indexes. Which simplify data imports and atomic updates.
But I have one case where I want to update certain properties of that model without triggering the indexing actions.

So i'm looking for either:

1. Some kind of flag that can be used with _post_put_hook, or:
2. A way to know which model properties/values have changed on that put() so I can add a condition wether to update indexes or not.

Thanks!

Comment: The harder part is monitoring properties to see if they have changed or not. since there isn't a method like that built into the `ndb.Model` base class. Data is stored in `_values`.

Comment: You can, just not directly with the hooks but they help. Use a higher level get to then to make a copy of the properties, create a hash of them as well.  in _pre_put then compare hashes, if different then look for changes and in our case store an audit trail of changes in a child entity along with who made the hances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to set a entity property that is not a ndb.Property (ie volatile) which you set explicitly when you want to avoid calling the logic in the _post_put_hook.

For example

from my zope days properties that wouldn't be saved where named `_v_somename`

so  explicitly `setattr(self,_v_no_hook,True)`  - obviously do this in a method ;-)

And then just check the flag in your `_post_put_hook`

```
if not getattr(self,'_v_no_hook`,False):
     # do something.not
```

You can do this with post put hooks as they are methods, rather than class methods, which most of the other hooks are.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Will use this approach.